# Mapping Classes

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

lets say i have 2 classes A and B . This classes having several indivuals calling them a' and b'.

a' got the following object properties: t,z
b' got the following object properties f, g

now i want to map both classes. If i use owl:equivalentTo the class A union B will have the object properties t,z,f,g. How can i map both classes if i dont want to have all object properties in there just lets say f,z. Some kind of SomeValuesFrom or? Another question is related to Sublclass of, what is the difference between using owl:equivalentTo and owl:subclass relating to my example.

Additional Information:

This paper may describe the best what i am trying to achieve.

https://bpt.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/pub/Public/GeroDecker/bpmdemo2008-bpmn2yawl.pdf

To map from one nation to another. From BPMN to YAWL with OWL. I already have a BPMN Ontology and a YAWL Ontology with all possibles constructs. Based on the two Ontologies i created one example(booking trip) with indivuals in BPMN and corresponding the transformation in YAWL. The third Ontology is my mapping Ontology were i imported the other Ontologies. The goal is to Map from BPMN to YAWL. I am using Protege 5.0 Desktop. . Corresponding i mapped externalTaskFactsType(YAWL) with scriptTask(BPMN) and stated the object property has_outgoing(BPMN) equals flowsinto(YAWL). Now the ExternalTaskFactsType should have all indiviuals from BPMN and also all object properties right? But there is an overlap. Normally in externalTaskFactstpye in YAWL there is no such attribute as has_incoming which is still there and has_outgoing is also present. All i want are the indivuals and the mapping from has_outoing to flowsinto not the other object properties that are belonging to BPMN. Also im not sure how to create the empty task shown in the paper. I mapped the inclusive gateway with externalTaskfactsType, but the result is a named task(with description). How can i delelte the name, that only the sequence flow is present(only indivual present and flowsinto). My Trip example looks like this:

i63.tinypic.com/acaj9z.png (cant post 2 links, put this infront http://)

The owl classes: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09067822138947987920(My project: run the Ontology MappingBetweenBPMNandYAWL and fix the imports for your project)

best regards
Richard

Comment: `A owl:equivalentTo B` is syntactic sugar for `A rdfs:subClassOf B` and `B rdfs:subClassOf A`.

Comment: And classes do not "have object properties". What you want does not work if you add `A owl:equivalentTo B` as reasoning in OWL is monotonic.

Comment: Classes don't have properties in OWL, individuals do.  "A union B" is the class of all Individuals that are either an A or a B. If an A has values for property t, then of course that same individual is an "A union B",so there's an "A union B"    that has a t value.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some code that actually shows what you're trying to do, and what you're trying to prevent.

Comment: i edited my question. Hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: i dont know why i made the effort to upload all my stuff and editing my question when after all there is no input from you guys. Kinda sad. Hoped really you could help me :(